# AWS Codestart Permissions to create a Project

Tags: aws-codestar

I have an IAM account from my work organization. When I try to create a project in CodeStar, I get a permissions denied error.
[image: Error in CodeStar]

Could somebody please let me know what all permissions should the account owner / root give to an IAM user / group so that they can create a project in CodeStar

Answer (score 0):

I think this link helps

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/setting-up.html

> Configure Permissions for IAM Users Complete these steps to set up IAM
> user permissions.
>
> To perform this step, sign in to the IAM console as a root user, an
> IAM administrator user in the account, or an IAM user or federated
> user with the associated AdministratorAccess managed policy or
> equivalent. Attach the AWSCodeStarFullAccess managed policy to the IAM
> user that is used to create the project.